# Extract href from javascript string

Tags: php, string

A function in PHP returns me following js snippet in a string

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function gformRedirect()
{
  document.location.href='https://plamsn.web/fr/demande-de-pret?montant=400%24&email=jon%40doe.com';
}
</script>
```

I want to extract, href from the above string

```
https://plamsn.web/fr/demande-de-pret?montant=400%24&email=jon%40doe.com
```

I tried the following

```
$hrefStartIndex = strpos($redirect, 'http');
$hrefEndIndex = strpos($redirect, ';}');
$href = substr($redirect, $hrefStartIndex, $hrefEndIndex);
```

This seems to give some issues and i am not sure if this is how i should go with, any pointer on how to go about it will be appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: for reference you stumble on to a JSONP request, maybe look more info that way? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
$url = "<script type=''text/javascript'> function gformRedirect(){document.location.href='https://plamsn.web/fr/demande-de-pret?montant=400%24&email=jon%40doe.com';}</script>";

$first_step = explode( 'document.location.href=' , $url );
$second_step = explode(";}" , $first_step[1] );
echo $second_step[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

Please remember to change the start position, if there are any changes in the string.

```
<?php
$url='<script type="text/javascript"> function gformRedirect(){document.location.href="https://plamsn.web/fr/demande-de-pret?montant=400%24&email=jon%40doe.com";}</script>';

$url=substr($url,81,strlen($url));
$url=rtrim($url,'";}</script>');
echo $url;
?>
```

Comment: it returns `://plamsn.web/fr/demande-de-pret?montant=400%24&email=jon%40doe.com`

Answer (score 1):

**solution using regex**:

```
<?php
    $url='<script type="text/javascript"> function gformRedirect(){document.location.href="https://plamsn.web/fr/demande-de-pret?montant=400%24&email=jon%40doe.com";}</script>';
    preg_match("/http[^\"]*/", $url, $output_array);
    echo $output_array[0];
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
add_filter( 'gform_confirmation', function ( $confirmation, $form, $entry, $ajax ) {
GFCommon::log_debug( __METHOD__ . '(): running.' );
if ( isset($form['confirmation']['type']) && isset($form['confirmation']['url']) && $form['confirmation']['type']="redirect" && $form['confirmation']['url']!="" && $form['id'] == 3) {
    $url          = esc_url_raw( $form['confirmation']['url'] );
    GFCommon::log_debug( __METHOD__ . '(): Redirect to URL: ' . $url );
    $confirmation = 'Thanks for contacting us! We will get in touch with you shortly.';
    $confirmation .= "<script>window.open('".$url."', '_blank');</script>";
}

return $confirmation;
}, 10, 4 );
```